# How to add javascript url dynamically in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xsl where I have to include a javascript, for which the src link is received from a web service response.

The service response xml looks like this:

```
<value>
  <scripturl>http://www.example.com/js/example.js?apikey=12345</scripturl>
</value>
```

and the script tag I have added in the xsl (I already have read the `scripturl` value in xsl and set in xsl variable named `scripturlxsl`) looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javscript" src="{scripturlxsl}"></script>
```

How would I make it work, as the page is not loading the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script url value is already in a variable, then this is what you would do:

```
<script type="text/javscript" src="{$scripturlxsl}"></script>
```

Comment: does 'xsl:attribute' work in this case? just tried that and it did not work. but it worked on image. am i missing the basic?. Your code worked for me. thanks.

Comment: Yes, you could use `xsl:attribute`.  In that case, you would put this between the `script` tags: `<xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="$scripturlxsl" /></xsl:attribute>`. As I think you can see, there wouldn't be any benefit to using `xsl:attribute` in this case.